# React-native component re-rendering but not updating props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass a prop (that I fetch from my database) from a screen to a first child component( component A). Then I want this component A to also pass the prop to another child component(component B).

The problem I have right now with my code is that, while both component re-render as I want them to when I fetch data from my database, component A prop updates, but component B prop doesn't.

I've already tried to not use props and to use the useContext hook to provide data to both those components but the issue remains the same.

Do you have any idea what's wrong with this code ?

The screen:

```
const screen = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]); //since the prop i want to pass is an array
    const dataIndexes = [1, 2, 3]
    //Fetching my data from firebase...
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const q = query(collection(db, "Data"), where('index', 'in', dataIndexes))
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            setData(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data()})));
        }
        getData();
     }, [])
    return(
   <View>
    <Component_A data={data}/>
   </View>
    )
}
```

The Component A :

```
const Component_A = (props) => {
    console.log(props.data)
    return (
        <View>
            <Component_B data={props.data}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

The component B :

```
const Component_B = (props) => {
    console.log(props.data)
    return(
        <></>
    )
}
```

The result of those console logs are the following:
-first render of component A: [] 
-first render of component B: [] 
-second render of component A: [populated array] (what I expect)
-second render of component B: [] (weird)

Since the component B does re-render according to those console logs, why doesn't its prop as well ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Verify `props.data` is empty by adding an element - to rule out a `console.log()` quirk. To component B add something like `<>{props.data.length}</>` and see what the result is.

Comment: Component B do not use the data in the render, you just have a console.log, try tu use the data and see what's happen, maybe try to print it just to test `<Text>{JSON.stringify(props.data)}</Text>`